# Deploy Angular App to domain "username.github.io"

Tags: angular, deployment

I'm trying to deploy an angular app on my user github page (like 'username.github.io') but I can't make it work.
These are the commands that I have used:

1. npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages
2. ng build --prod --base-href="myusername.github.io"
3. ngh --message="MESSAGE" --branch="master" --dir=dist/projectname

the path shows 'gladdental.github.io/gladdental.github.io/login' instead of 'gladdental.github.io/login'.

You can check here:[gladdental.github.io](https://gladdental.github.io/).

My repository: https://github.com/gladdental/gladdental.github.io

Could you help me this please? Thanks.

Comment: Try this once `ng github-pages:deploy --base-href /`

Comment: I did it but it shows an error "The specified command ("github-pages:deploy") is invalid".

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Thanks to you, I edited a little bit of the command "ng build --prod --base-href /" and it work fine. Thanks you

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, Happy coding :)